# Setting pointers to structs

Tags: c++

I have the following struct:

```
struct Datastore_T
{
 Partition_Datastores_T  cmtDatastores; // bytes 0 to 499
 Partition_Datastores_T  cdhDatastores; // bytes 500 to 999
 Partition_Datastores_T  gncDatastores; // bytes 1000 to 1499
 Partition_Datastores_T  inpDatastores; // bytes 1500 1999
 Partition_Datastores_T  outDatastores; // bytes 2000 to 2499
 Partition_Datastores_T  tmlDatastores; // bytes 2500 to 2999
 Partition_Datastores_T  sm_Datastores; // bytes 3000 to 3499
};
```

I want to set a char* to point to a struct of this type like so:

```
struct Datastore_T datastores;

// Elided: datastores is initialized with data here

char* DatastoreStartAddr = (char*)&datastores;
memset(DatastoreStartAddr, 0, 3500);
```

The problem I have is that DatastoreStartAddr always has a value of zero when it should point to the struct that has been initialized with data.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: What I mean by zero is that the "values" in the structure are all zeros even after I initialize the structure.  The address is not zero, it is the values in the struct that are zero.

Edit: I think I am asking the question wrong.  Let's start over.  If I have a struct that is initialized with data, and another object maintains a field member that is a pointer to that struct, if the struct is changed directly:

```
struct Datastore_T datastores;
char* DatastoreStartAddr = (char*)&datastores;

datastores.cmtDatastores.u16Region[0] = Scheduler.GetMinorFrameCount(); // byte 40,41
datastores.cmtDatastores.u16Region[1] = Scheduler.GetMajorFrameCount(); // byte 42,43
```

Shouldn't I be able to access these changes using the DatastoreStartAddr pointer?

**EDIT:** The following code tries to read the data set in datastores, but using the pointer to the struct:

```
            CMT_UINT8_Tdef PayLoadBuffer[1500]= {NULL};
            int TDIS = 0;
            int DIS = 0;
            int DSA = 0;

            //copy DataStore info using address and size offsets
            if ((PayLoadBuffer + TDIS + DIS) < IndvDEMMax)
            {
               memcpy((PayLoadBuffer + TDIS), Datastores+DSA, DIS);
               TDIS += DIS;
            }
```

In the `memcpy((PayLoadBuffer + TDIS), Datastores+DSA, DIS)` line, Datastores should point to structure and attempts to access an offset in that structure.  But since the value is always zero, it copies zero in the PayLoadBuffer.

Comment: Can't you just `memset(&datastores, 0, sizeof(struct Datastore_T));` or something?

Comment: Since this is C++, you can use `DataStore_T datastores = DataStore_T();` (value initialization for the win!)

Comment: @Bobby If it is your initilization code that you now say is failing WHY DON'T YOU SHOW IT? And what has the memset() stuff got to do with this? You do realise that the memset call will zero the struct, I suppose?

Comment: I second Neil's request - you've posted loads of code that isn't relevant and you replaced the relevant code with a comment.

Comment: Because of alignment `Datastore_T` will not occupy just 3,500 bytes. Use `sizeof(datastores)`.

Comment: Further, why don't you show us the *result* of something that you claim isn't right *and* tell us what you think it should be? It may be that the problem is not in setting or changing the structure, but in the way you are attempting to access it. "It doesn't work." is never enough, rather you should tell us "This code does Foo, but I was expecting Bar.".

Comment: OK, you've shown the code that sets some values, and you say that you get zero when you read them back. Could you show the code that tries to read them back? Also, could you check that the "frame count" values are actually non-zero? You should also check that the memory layout is what you're expecting; the compiler may insert padding between the fields of structures.

Comment: @Bobby Did you write this code (which as posted is wrong)? Please respond. You do know how the comment mechanism works?

Comment: @Bobby The default way of passing structures to functions in both C and C++ is to pass them by value. If you do that, the changes get made to the parameter inside the function, not the thing outside the function. Is it possible you are passing things by value (i.e. not using the & operator) rather than by reference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why you are getting an address of zero, but I would guess the code you don't show has something to do with it. Some other points:

- Consider using an array of `Partition_Datastores_T` inside your struct
- Do not use magic numbers for struct sizes, you want `sizeof(Datastore_T )`
- There is no need for the intermediate `char*`

**Edit:** Bobby, to answer your supplementary question - yes you should be able to access it through a pointer, but not through a `char *` (without jumping through some hoops). You want:

```
struct Datastore_T datastores;
struct Datastore_T * DatastoreStartAddr = &datastores;
```

and when you use that pointer:

```
DatastoreStartAddr->cmtDatastores.u16Region[0] = Scheduler.GetMinorFrameCount();
```

Please note the use of the `->` operator.

Comment: Such an explicit typecast to char* will be needed if you want to use pointer arithmetics with 1-byte-alignment.  

I also disagree with your "use an array" - the symbol names are there for easy identification/meaning of the variable. You would strip the meaning of the symbol prefixes "sm_" "tml" and so on if you have to use an array where you have to address the values by index and not by name.

Comment: @Robert The cast is not needed for memset(), which is what he's doing. And I didn't say "use an array", I said he should consider doing so. Without knowing how he's using the struct, it's hard to say if the named substructures have meaning or not.

Comment: @Neil: if the code above would make the whole program you would be completely right: memset takes a generic void* pointer as first parameter and no explicit cast is necessary. But because the majority of posted code on SO are only fragments it's more likely that the cast to a char-pointer has a meaning (for example for speeding up coding following pointer arithmetics).

Comment: @Robert No, it is far, far more likely that the OP doesn't know what he is doing.

Comment: @Neil: with all the question edits it becomes clearer and clearer that you are right.

Comment: @Robert To you maybe - not to me.

Comment: @Neil: This has a `C++` tag, so there's no need for the `struct` in front of the type name.

Comment: @sbi Thank you for that useless bit of information. Do you think I don't know that? Do you think my answer would be improved by, at the same time I am trying to work out what the OP is asking about, I change the syntax (which is quite legal C++)  of his question? This is the sort of thing that gives mindless pedantry a bad name.

Comment: @Neil: I'm not sure why you're so annoyed. Yes, I'm pretty sure you know that. I am, OTOH, not so sure everybody else does - especially not the OP. Since this usually unnecessary C-ism is something we see again and again, I feel the highest voted answer should point that out. If you feel different, that's fine with me, it's your answer, after all.

Comment: @sbi Your comment was explicitly addressed to me. If you wanted to point this out to Bobby you should have addressed it to him, added an answer of your own, or made a comment on the question itself.

Comment: @Neil: Since I felt the answer was missing something, it was addressed to the person who wrote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

i just tested your code and it is not zero. Try to post bigger piece

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it in the wrong order - should be like this

```
struct Datastore_T datastores;
char* DatastoreStartAddr = (char*)&datastores;
memset(DatastoreStartAddr, 0, sizeof(Datastore_T));

// Elided: datastores is initialized with data here
```

Now datastores is still initialized. And like everyone else says you might want this instead

```
struct Datastore_T * DatastoreStartAddr = datastores;
memset((void *)DatastoreStartAddr, 0, sizeof(Datastore_T));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the code you are not showing is correct. It might be wise to show it to us for scrutiny. Likely, what I say below is not the problem at all.

Because of the cast, it *might* be that you're having [aliasing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing_%28computing%29) issues here. If you have set aggressive compiler optimization flags (e.g. `-fno-strict-aliasing` on gcc), the compiler would assume that those two pointers can never refer to the same thing, because they have different types. Then either or both of the representations might be cached in different CPU registers, so updates to one would never be reflected in the other.

Again, this is a long shot. Considering the size of your `struct` (I didn't see that when I started answering your duplicate question), it is very unlikely that it would reside anywhere else but in main memory. But you could try turn down your compiler optimizations and see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

At what point is your structure's values zero?   If it's before the cast and `memset()`, the problem is with your initialization.  If it is after the cast and `memset()`, then the values in your structure are zero because `memset()` overwrote with 0's the values you had initialized it with.  The values in `datastores` should also be zero after the `memset()`.